# Pub build produces warning every build: 'Can't find 'animate' in the library 'angular'.'

Tags: dart, angular-dart

I'm boldly stepping into the world of AngularDart, admittedly not knowing too much Dart itself yet.  I'm creating a new application that does nothing (yet), except includes the latest 'angular' package.

I'm using Dart 1.2.0 and AngularDart 0.9.9.

Very simple pubspec:

```
name: myapp
dependencies:
  angular: any
```

My app layout:

```
pubspec.yaml
pubspec.lock
\lib
\packages
\web
```

In web I have a simple myapp.dart:

```
import 'package:angular/angular.dart';

main() {
}
```

My build seems to work fine, but I get the following warning:

```
        Dart: Build
        [Warning from Dart2JS on myapp|web/myapp.dart]:
        packages\angular\angular.dart:31:23: Hint: Can't find 'animate' in the library 'angular'.
        Is 'animate' spelled right?
        @MirrorsUsed(targets: const [
        ^^^^^^^^
```

My question is, what does this mean, and is this anything to be concerned about?

Comment: Can you try 'Pub Upgrade' (context menu on your `pubspec.yaml`). AngularDart 0.9.9 was published yesterday. Please report if something changed?

Comment: Hi Gunter, actually, I must have bumped pub upgrade at some stage, because it seems I was running AngularDart 0.9.9 after all. When I set my dependency explicitly to 0.9.8, the warning goes away!

I'm leaving this question open, because the warning still occurs for  0.9.9.

Comment: DartEditor does this automatically whenever you save pubspec.yaml. Thanks for the feedback.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This was a bug in AngularDart 0.9.9 and is fixed in current versions.